# call_user_func_array vs $controller->$method($params)?

Tags: php

I 'm using this in my code:

```
 call_user_func_array ( array ($controller, $method ), $this->params );
```

but I found out that the code below does the same thing:

```
 $controller->$method($this->params);
```

**Is there any difference between the two versions?**

Thanks

Adam Ramadhan

Answer (score 5, accepted):

They are not the same.

If `$method` is `showAction` and `$this->params` is `array(2, 'some-slug')`, then the first call would be equivalent to:

```
$controller->showAction(2, 'some-slug');
```

Whereas the second would be:

```
$controller->showAction(array(2, 'some-slug'));
```

Which one you want to use depends on how the rest of your system works (your controllers in particular). I personally would probably go with the first.

Comment: ah i see, so if we want to use the params the first one will be ($number,$string) the second one $data['0'] $data['1'], how about peformance do they do any difference ? ( major ) ? if not then maybe i should stick to the first one. because yeah my application got quite a view.

Comment: Any performance difference would be only a small handful of opcodes, so don't worry about that in the least.

Answer (score 5):

They work alike. The only significant difference is that `$controller->$nonexistant()` would generate a fatal error. While `call_user_func_array` fails with just an E_WARNING should `$method` not exist.

**Fun fact**. Should your $controller harbor a closure $method, then you would actually have to combine both approaches:

```
call_user_func_array ( $controller->$method, $this->params );
```

Answer (score 0):

They are doing the same thing, but the second form is shorter, clearer, and faster. Prefer it.

Answer (score 0):

```
$controller->$method($this->params);
```

In this case your function will get an array of params and who know how many of them can be and who know what inside $params[0] can be

```
function myaction($params){
    echo $params[0].$params[1].$params[2];
    }
```

In another case you can get exactly a variable from array of params

```
call_user_func_array ( array ($controller, $method ), $this->params );
```

Prime example
You have URL like

```
http://example.com/newsShow/150/10-20-2018
```

or like that

```
http://example.com/newsShow/150/10-20-2018/someotherthings/that/user/can/type
```

in both case you will get only what you need to get

```
call_user_func_array ( array ($controller, myaction ), $this->params );

function myaction($newsid,$newsdate){
    echo $newsid; // will be 150
    echo $newsdate; // will be 10-20-2018
    }
```